# Dynamic or Cascading Dropdowns - how?

Tags: custom-fields, menu

I am trying to create a set of dropdown lists that are dynamically linked so that the values in list 2 are driven by what is selected in list 1.

Example:
Consider an address (in Nepal) which has a Country(1), Region (4), Zone(14), District(75), Municipality(133).

I want to be able to select a region, which will then display the zones in that region only - select a zone, which will then display the districts in that particular zone - select a district, and then same with municipality.

Is this possible?

Thanks, Joe.

Comment: Can you make this clearer in terms of how this data is being stored. The address function already does the required for Country/Region, ie if you choose Nepal you should then get the list of Regions for Nepal assuming you have enabled them via Localisation. For the next levels I think you would need to be adding the values to the County table etc as these are not  included. But don't want to spend time detailing that if you are wanting these as Custom Fields rather than as an actual 'Location' Address.

Comment: OK, thanks for all the great answers and comments which have allowed to think in a bit more detail about how I ideally want this structured.  Basically I need 4 levels.  In the following list the left hand col is the US address and the right col is the desired Nepali equivalent:
**US Address == Nepali Equiv**  Country == Country  State == Zone  County == District  City ==  Municipality

Comment: I checked out the county import and it looks as though it will do the trick by mofifying the values.  The tradeoff is that I lose districts but I can live with that.

Comment: The localizaition for Nepal does not appear to be working - Select NEPAL from the Country list but no values appear in the county field.  I have a workaround being he import as mentioned above - just thought i'd mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CiviCRM already does this out-of-the-box to 3 levels deep (In the US they are called Country/State/County). Populating the `civicrm_county` table in your database with the Nepalese equivalent of counties will get that 3-level chain-select going.

Going down more levels than that isn't supported by core forms... you could create some custom fields for it, or you could just skip over some of the levels. For example, choosing from among 14 zones really isn't that hard - why ask the user to choose a region first?

Comment: Excellent - many thanks - that sounds like the most sensible thing to do.
This will be a bit of trial and error my part having never attempted such a thing before, so you may not have hear the last of me yet!
Thanks again.

Comment: And sorry - to answer your question about why ask the user for a higher level value- there will be a large amount of old data going into the DB and a lot of the info is actually missing, and there are cases where the only the higher level info is available.

Comment: Cool. @jkobier don't forget to "accept" this answer. StackExchange still thinks this question is unanswered until you do.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular use case, you may also want to consider modifying the [County Lookup](https://github.com/PalanteJon/coop.palantetech.countylookup) extension to pull in some levels of detail with Google Maps data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this some more once I get the basic functionality working.